# Using Exception For Divide Array By An Other Array

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I an writing program with divided one array from an other array this program also cover exception for the the problem maybe happen in program.the problem in program is the output is not in order. I need to print the result like this:

```
before division start-
program is proessing 2-
division by zero-
program is proessing 10-
program is proessing 15-
.....
```

If you compile code you see the answer has been messed up.

```html
public class exception {
public static void main (String args[]){
 //int[]pooya =new int[10];
 int[] pooya={20,4,80,75,48,30};
 int[]java={10,0,8,5,12,3,78,2,12};
 System.out.println("beofore division start");
 for(int i=0;i<=pooya.length;i++){
   for(int x=0;x<=java.length;x++){
 try{
  int y=pooya[i]/java[x];
  System.out.println("program is prossing "+y);
  }
 catch(ArithmeticException poo){
  System.out.println("division by zero");
 }
 catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException po){
  System.out.println("item is not match");
 }
    }
    }
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Right now your program's logic is not following the logic in the expected result. 
You are using nested for-cycle, which acts like that:

1. First cycle that is looping for i is set to 0, e.g. it gets "20" as
   it is the zero element from ***pooya*** array. Second cycle tries to
   divide 20 to all the element from array ***java***, e.g. first
   20/10, then 20/0, then 20/8 and so on till the end of the ***java***
   array.
2. After all these operation will the program return to
   switching to the next value from ***pooya*** array and will divide
   this element to all the elements from ***java*** array.

---

Another thing is that in your for-loops you are exceeding the sizes of your arrays and that is causing your **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** exceptions.

```
    int[] pooya = {20, 4, 80, 75, 48, 30}
```

This array has length 6, but indexing starts from 0, meaning you have valid elements **pooya[0], pooya[1], pooya[2], pooya[3], pooya[4**] and **pooya[5]** - six elements. Invoking pooya[6] is causing **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** exception. That is why you should remove your equals sign from your for-loop definition, because i should never reach 6:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pooya.length; i++)
```

---

If you want to have the result you have described for arrays

```
    int[] pooya = {20, 4, 80, 75, 48, 30};
    int[] java = {10, 0, 8, 5, 12, 3, 78, 2, 12};
```

Then you should refactor your code to use only one cycle, something like this:

```
        int[] pooya = {20, 4, 80, 75, 48, 30};
        int[] java = {10, 0, 8, 5, 12, 3, 78, 2, 12};
        System.out.println("Before division start");
        for (int i = 0; i < pooya.length; i++) {
            try {
                int y = pooya[i] / java[i];
                System.out.println("Program is processing " + y);
            } catch (ArithmeticException poo) {
                System.out.println("Division by zero");
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException po) {
                System.out.println("Item is not match");
            }
        }
```

With this implementation you will have result for 20/10, 4/0, 80/8, 75/5, 48/12 and 30/3 and then it will not proceed, because there are no more elements in the first array to be used for dividing and you will not need the catch that is for **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**.